# c# Detect Rectangles in Image

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I'm looking to detect and get a array of Rects, one for each rectangle, in the image below. How might I do this in c#?

Basically I'm trying to scan the image taken of the screen and parse the array of windows.

Rect being some form of (xloc,yloc,xsize,ysize)
Returned array: rectangles = ParseRects(image);

[image]

Comment: Nice EVE Online screenshot you have there ;)

Comment: @PicMickael ;).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your best option will be to use the [AForge.Net library](http://www.aforgenet.com).

The following code is derived from the documentation for the `ShapeChecker` class, and you may want to look at the documentation to further familiarize yourself.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Open your image
    string path = "test.png";
    Bitmap image = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(path);

    // locating objects
    BlobCounter blobCounter = new BlobCounter();

    blobCounter.FilterBlobs = true;
    blobCounter.MinHeight = 5;
    blobCounter.MinWidth = 5;

    blobCounter.ProcessImage(image);
    Blob[] blobs = blobCounter.GetObjectsInformation();

    // check for rectangles
    SimpleShapeChecker shapeChecker = new SimpleShapeChecker();

    foreach (var blob in blobs)
    {
        List<IntPoint> edgePoints = blobCounter.GetBlobsEdgePoints(blob);
        List<IntPoint> cornerPoints;

        // use the shape checker to extract the corner points
        if (shapeChecker.IsQuadrilateral(edgePoints, out cornerPoints))
        {
            // only do things if the corners form a rectangle
            if (shapeChecker.CheckPolygonSubType(cornerPoints) == PolygonSubType.Rectangle)
            {
                // here i use the graphics class to draw an overlay, but you
                // could also just use the cornerPoints list to calculate your
                // x, y, width, height values.
                List<Point> Points = new List<Point>();
                foreach (var point in cornerPoints)
                {
                    Points.Add(new Point(point.X, point.Y));
                }

                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
                g.DrawPolygon(new Pen(Color.Red, 5.0f), Points.ToArray());

                image.Save("result.png");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The original input:
[image: original input]

The resultant image:[image]

Comment: Hey! I actually managed to get almost this result, using the same program. I'm accepting your answer but I'd like to get more input if you will give it, do you think filtering out all color but the range the windows are would be better? I need to introduce a random background behind it and have it still be able to recognize ONLY the windows. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Christian I'll be perfectly honest: random backgrounds are going to be hard. You can probably use the blob detection in my answer, but background subtraction is a science in itself. I'm guessing this random background is animated, so I would take two frames, and XOR them to get a static image to use.

Comment: @GregBuehler : BlobCounter class is coming from some Dll? if so, please share the dll location..Thanks.

Comment: BlobCounter is in the AForge.Imaging namespace. See: http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7d5c028-7a23-e27d-ffd0-5df57cbd31a6.htm

Comment: For anyone finding that AForge is looking a bit out-of-date, it has been incorporated into the Accord Machine Learning framework: http://accord-framework.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can see the line Detection by Hough transformation
and Corner detection.
Some algorithms have probably already been implemented in C#